# need help with programming a word finder in python

Tags: python, list-manipulation

hi i have a question about python which im a rookie at:

i have a text file which contains a list of words (around 23000) in alphabetical order, like a small dictionary
each line is a word in that textfile

i have to make a programme that asks the user for nine letters, and then the programme is supposed to rerange these letters and find all words in the textfile which match this set of nine letters

im kind of stuck in the coding of this programme, and i would like some assistance please

this is what i've done

```
Nian = raw_input ("Type in nine letters :")

filename = "dictionary.txt"
fil = open(filename, "r")

lines = fil.read()

tx4 = lines.strip()

a = Nian[0]    
b = Nian[1]      
c = Nian[2]       
d = Nian[3]       
e = Nian[4]    
f = Nian[5]      
g = Nian[6]    
h = Nian[7]     
i = Nian[8]

for w in lines[0:23005]:
       if a or b or c or d or e or f or g or h or i in lines:
       print w
```

Comment: Have you written any code yet?  This is a "teach you to fish, not sell you a fish" type of website.  As a start, in python, look at the `itertools` package for utility functions that generate things like permutations.

Comment: If you need to use all nine letters, that's easy. Just sort them, sort the letters of each word, and compare. If you can use fewer than nine, the comparison is a little harder, but not much.

Comment: @ericcoo: Edit your question to include what you just wrote.

Comment: @ericcoo: Also, while cleaning up your question, please use Capital Letters at the start of each sentence.  And use Capital "I" to refer to yourself.  Standard well-written English really helps.

Answer (score 2):

So if it's an exact match of those 9 letters, we can be a little tricky here. Instead of creating all those permutations and checking each one, merely sort the words into alphabetical order using the python built-in `sorted` function ([doc](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted)) and compare the result.

The "trick" here is realizing you're looking for an anagram for those 9 letters. For Example,
'terse' and 'reset' are anagrams of each other, but if you sort them they both turn into 'eerst'.

Even if you're not looking for exact matches you can still use this trick to make optimizations.

As for the rest of the program, if you look for some basic tutorials on reading a text file with python, I'm sure you'll be able to get through the rest of it. Good luck!

Comment: Yes, this is the simplest and most efficient way.  Generating all permutations is not the way to go. What if you had 20 letters instead?  20! = a very big number, and the algorithm would take forever, but this solution would still work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to proceed:

1. read the file into a set() object, do not forget to remove `'\n'` at the end of the lines if you use the `readlines()` method of the `file` object.
2. iterate over all permutations, using http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations and check if one of these permutations is in your set. Maybe you have to map a tuple to a string, using the `join` method of `str` is helpful.

You know that there are `9! = 362880` permutations ?

Comment: Generating all permutations is a terribly inefficient way to find anagrams. See my comment above.

Comment: Well, thanks, but it's not my idea. I read it in *Programming Pearls*.

Answer (score 0):

What pops into my mind first are sets.

This may be not the ideal solution, but should do the job:

```
match_letters = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i'}
for line in file:
    line = line.strip()
    line_letters = set(line)
    # test whether any letter from match_letters is in line_letters
    if line_letters & match_letters:
        print(line)
```

**OR**, if I misunderstood and you are looking for words that contain **ALL** nine letters:

```
    if line_letters >= match_letters:
        print(line)
```

**OR**, if you are looking for words that contain **ONLY** those nine letters:

```
    if line_letters <= match_letters:
        print(line)
```